# $ \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to + \infty } \frac{{\log \left( {\frac{{x - 1}}{x}} \right)}}{{\log \left( {\frac{{x + 1}}{x}} \right)}} = - 1 $

Tags: calculus

What do I need to do to show the following limit?
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \frac{{\log \left( {\frac{{x - 1}}{x}} \right)}}{{\log \left( {\frac{{x + 1}}{x}} \right)}} =  - 1
$$

Comment: Using L'Hospital  rule

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)}{\log\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)}&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}\\&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\log(1-h)}{\log(1+h)}\\&=-\lim_{h\to0}\left[\frac{\log(1-h)}{-h}\frac{1}{\frac{\log(1+h)}{h}}\right]\\&=-1\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Set $\dfrac1x=h$ and use $\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1+h)}h=1$

Answer (score 1):

Only a complement to @Sabaga Bachir: answer : with $h= \frac{1}{x}$ we have

$$\frac{\log(\frac{x-1}{x})}{\log(\frac{x+1}{x})}= \frac{\log(1-h)}{\log(1+h)}=-\frac{h +\frac{h^2}{2} + \frac{h^3}{3} + \ldots}{h -\frac{h^2}{2} + \frac{h^3}{3}  -\ldots}$$

We get  a series expansion around zero

$$\frac{\log(1-h)}{\log(1+h)} = -( 1+h+\frac{h^2}{2}+\frac{5 h^3}{12}+\frac{7 h^4}{24}+\\ + \frac{191 \,h^5}{720}+\frac{33 \,h^6}{160}+\frac{11779\, h^7}{60480}+\frac{19309\, h^8}{120960}+\frac{79771\,
h^9}{518400}+\\ +\frac{945251\, h^{10}}{7257600}+
\frac{60920509\, h^{11}}{479001600}+\frac{11710379\, h^{12}}{106444800}+ \ldots ) $$

It is worth noting that all the coefficients of the series in the brackets are positive.